# How to clear out a drawn texture from the screen in libGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

I am trying to clear out the drawn texture from the screen.

Lets take a classic game example - in many games when the character goes through the coins the coins clears out from the screen and displays a sweet animation like fade in and fade out the points collected from that coin(+10) and show the coin exploding animation on that position.

I want to do something similar to that.
I am using `SpriteBatch` to draw the texture region like below.

**Setting texture Region:**

```
(...)
 public Texture texture;
    public TextureRegion coin;
    texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/texture.png"));
    texture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Nearest, TextureFilter.Nearest); 
    coin = new TextureRegion(texture, 0, 336, 65, 73);
 (...)
```

**Drawing the texture into screen :**

```
 public SpriteBatch batcher;
 batcher = new SpriteBatch();
 batcher.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
  batcher.begin();
    batcher.enableBlending();
    batcher.draw(coin, x, y, 65,73);
    (...)
    (...)
  batcher.end();
```

The game character is also drawn using the same logic shown above.
Now when the game character will collide with the coin that I have drawn,the coin must be cleared(vanished) and some animation or big font like +50 must fadein and fadeout in that position.I tried but didn't find anything that would do this.
So how to do that ?

Comment: I would recommend reading up on [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). It looks like you've got only a *View* and no *Model*.

Comment: @Anko No !! I know whats MVC but it would be a very long code if I paste it in here because there are various classes that i am using for performing various tasks. I wrote the above code just to make it explain better and just to show how i am using libGDX to draw the textures thats it .

Comment: OK, so why not destroy the `Coin` instance and create a `ScoreDisplay` instance where it was? Shouldn't that cause your view to stop drawing the coin sprite and start drawing a *+10* score text?

Comment: If i destroy the coin object then how will the `batcher.draw(coin, x, y, 65,73);` work it will start throwing error on that line .

Comment: I think you should make an `ArrayList<GameObject> gameObjects` and between your `batcher`'s `begin` and `end`, do `for (GameObject o : gameObjects) { batcher.draw(gameObject.sprite, gameObject.x, gameObject.y, ...); }`. That way, you can just add or remove `Coin`s from `gameObjects` to control whether they're drawn or not. Then `gameObjects` is your **model** and your `batcher` the **view**. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: @Anko OO so i would have to just remove the object that i dont want to draw ,from the arraylist right ? Ok i would try that.. ! Actually I have followed the structure given in [Kilobolt zombiebird Tutorials](http://www.kilobolt.com/day-3-understanding-the-libgdx-framework.html) as thats the best way to get into learning libGDX and i am new to both libGDX and game development.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create a **class** for your coin object, and then collect all the coins in an array (`Sprite[] coin`), so whenever a collision occurs (player-coin), you call `coins[i].destroy`, where you can properly dispose all the referenced resources, or reset position for the next coin ?

For drawing :

```
 for (int i = 0; i <= quantity of coins; i++) {
          coin[i].draw(spriteBatch);
    }
```

For detecting collision :

```
 for (int i = 0; i <= quantity of coins; i++) {
         if (player.collide(coin[i])) {
             coin[i].applyFadeOut();
             score += 10;
             coin[i].destroy();
    }
```

[image]